# Which latest version of Rails does Jruby (9.0.4.0) support?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

Search doesn't give a definite answer. Does it at least support 4.2 with PG? Does it support jsonb columns?

Answer (score 0):

Rails does support Ruby versions and JRuby declares Ruby version compatibility. believe for Rails 4.2 Ruby **>= 1.9.3** is needed, thus JRuby **1.7.x** (MRI 1.9.3 compatible) **as well as 9.0.x** (MRI 2.2 compatible) **will work**.

be aware that `ActiveRecord` does not support JRuby directly as its using DB drivers that use C-extensions. however, you can use `ActiveRecord-JDBC-Adapter` which provides adapters for JRuby using Java's JDBC drivers for data-bases.